# Ruby Program for finding local maxima doesn't pass one test

Tags: arrays, ruby, math

I have a program for finding peaks (local maxima) in ruby that passes all but one test. Personally, I think my program is ok, but maybe I'm not taking into account an assumed neighborhood size that isn't specified in the problem, but was suggested by someone else who also attempted it.

Here's what I have so far.

```
def pick_peaks(arr)
  pos = []
  peaks =[]
  peak_set = {pos: [], peaks: []}

  for i in 1..arr.length-2
    if arr[i-1] < arr[i] && arr[i] >= arr[i+1] 
      unless edge_plateau?(arr, i)
      peak_set[:pos] << i
      peak_set[:peaks] << arr[i]
    end
  end
end
  peak_set_alt = peak_set.collect{|k,v| [k.to_s, v]}.to_h
  peak_set_alt
end

def edge_plateau?(array, position)
  edge_plateau_left = true
  edge_plateau_right = true
  i = 1
  until i == position
    edge_plateau_left = false if array[0] != array[i]
    i += 1
  end

  i = array.length-2
  until i == position
  edge_plateau_right = false if array[i] != array.last
  i -= 1
end
  edge_plateau_left or edge_plateau_right
end
```

Here's the test that it needs to pass but I don't know the original array, so that's a bit of a challenge.

```
Expected: {"pos"=>[2, 7, 14, 20], "peaks"=>[5, 6, 5, 5]}, instead got: {"pos"=>[2, 7, 11, 14, 20], "peaks"=>[5, 6, 3, 5, 5]}
```

I'm getting an extra peak in the middle but that should be ok if it's a local maxima, right?

UPDATE

Thanks to a suggestion I found the test array

```
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Clyde, do you also have a source array that fails the test? Or only peaks and indices? In the worst case you can "hack" it, by submitting fake function that just returns everything as "peaks" and thus get full data in the  test feedback. Having the source array you should be easily able to debug your code.

Comment: I only have the peaks and indices, but based on my code and these tests, I can infer that the values around the three at position 11 have to be less than 3. But you have pretty cool idea... Thanks!

Comment: Clyde, see my answer. As I expected there you falsely report `3` in the `2, 3, 3, 4, 5` sub-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more Ruby-like way to find the local maxima.

**Code**

```
def locale_maxima(arr)
  last_idx = arr.size - 1
  peaks, pos =
    ([[-Float::INFINITY, nil]] +
     arr.each_with_index.reject { |v,i| i < last_idx && v == arr[i+1] } +
     [[-Float::INFINITY, nil]]
    ).each_cons(3).
      select { |(n1,_), (n2,_), (n3,_)| n1 < n2 && n2 > n3 }.
      map { |_,max_pair,_| max_pair }.
      transpose
  { pos: pos, peaks: peaks }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3]
locale_maxima arr 
  #=> { :pos  =>[2, 7, 14, 21],
  #     :peaks=>[5, 6,  5,  5] }
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
  last_idx = arr.size - 1
    #=> 23
```

Where there are consecutive equal values, which may represent inflection points (a complication), remove all but the last. To report the indices of the local maxima we therefore need to save indices before removing the duplicates.

```
  b = arr.each_with_index.reject { |v,i| i < last_idx && v == arr[i+1] }      
    #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [5, 2], [4, 3], [3, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [6, 7],
    #    [4, 8], [1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 12], [4, 13], [5, 14], [3, 15],
    #    [2, 16], [1, 17], [2, 18], [3, 19], [5, 21], [4, 22], [3, 23]]
```

Notice that `[3,11]` and `[5, 20]` have been removed.

Tack on pairs at the beginning and end that cannot be local maxima (`nil` is arbitrary).

```
  c = [[-Float::INFINITY, nil]] + b + [[-Float::INFINITY, nil]] 
    #=> [[-Infinity, nil], [1, 0], [2, 1], [5, 2], [4, 3], [3, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], 
    #    [6, 7], [4, 8], [1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 12], [4, 13], [5, 14], [3, 15], [2, 16],
    #    [1, 17], [2, 18], [3, 19], [5, 21], [4, 22], [3, 23], [-Infinity, nil]]
```

Use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to produce an enumerator that will be used to identify the local maxima.

```
  d = c.each_cons(3)
    #=> #<Enumerator:
    #   [[-Infinity, nil], [1, 0], [2, 1], [5, 2], [4, 3], [3, 4], [2, 5], 
    #    [3, 6], [6, 7], [4, 8], [1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 12], [4, 13], [5, 14],
    #    [3, 15], [2, 16], [1, 17], [2, 18], [3, 19], [5, 21], [4, 22],
    #    [3, 23], [-Infinity, nil]]:each_cons(3)> 
  e = d.select { |(n1,_), (n2,_), (n3,_)| n1 < n2 && n2 > n3 }
    #=> [[[2, 1], [5, 2], [4, 3]],
    #    [[3, 6], [6, 7], [4, 8]],
    #    [[4, 13], [5, 14], [3, 15]],
    #    [[3, 19], [5, 21], [4, 22]]] 
  f = e.map { |_,max_pair,_| max_pair }
    #=> [[5, 2], [6, 7], [5, 14], [5, 21]]
  peaks, pos = f.transpose
    #=> [[5, 6, 5, 5], [2, 7, 14, 21]] 
  { pos: pos, peaks: peaks }
    #=> {:pos=>[2, 7, 14, 21], :peaks=>[5, 6, 5, 5]}
```

Comment: Hey Cary! Really compact solution, but I like the use of enumerators, and how you explain each part. I hope I get more chances to practice these types of techniques!

Answer (score 0):

Well there are more than one bug in your code.

Try your code on following data

```
pick_peaks([0,1,10,1,2,2,3,1,10,1,0])
```

You'll get

> {"pos"=>[2, 4, 6, 8], "peaks"=>[10, 2, 3, 10]}

Obviously `2` here is a bug. So the source of the bug here is `arr[i] >= arr[i+1]`

Also unless it  is shomehow explicitly stated in the task, you seem to handle edges wrong. Consider

```
pick_peaks([0,0,10,1,2,2,3,1,10,0,0])
```

You'll get

> {"pos"=>[4, 6], "peaks"=>[2, 3]}

missing both `10` on the left and on the right.

Without exact task it is hard to say definitely but at the first glance it seems that your algorithm is to complicated both in terms of code and `Big-O`. Why you don't just go once through the array and track whether your are climbing up, staying plain or going down?

**Update**

Here is a piece of code to illustrate my last suggestion. I'm not good at Ruby so my example code would be in JavaScript so you can run it in your browser console:

```
function pick_peaks(arr) {
   var prevUp = true; //let the start be a peak
   var peaks = [];
   var lastUpInd = 0;

   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
      if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) {
         prevUp = true;
         lastUpInd = i + 1;
      }
      else if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
         if(prevUp) {
               for(var j = lastUpInd; j <= i; j++) {
                  peaks.push([j, arr[j]]);
             }
         }
         prevUp = false;
      }       
   }

   // additionally handle the end to let it be a peak   
   if(prevUp)
   {
        for(var j = lastUpInd; j <= i; j++) {
              peaks.push([j, arr[j]]);
        }
   }
   return peaks;
}
```

If you don't want the ends to be possible peaks just init `prevUp` with `false` and remove last `if` with inner `for` after a comment